# How Total Station Works Mathematically?

Tags: geometry

I am working on some avr programming for a robot which can understand elevation of an object in distance for now that object is a mirror , I wonder how total station cameras works I mean mathematical formula

[image]

The only information you have is $x$ and $c$ in what formula I can get the elevation of `B`

If it's too basic to ask here sorry I am newbie in math. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\beta =x\sin(c)$$
check : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle

Comment: You don't need to indent displayed formulas (enclosed in double dollar signs); they're automatically centred. The indentation is interpreted as indicating a block quote, which is a verbatim quote in which the dollar signs are interpreted literally.

Comment: @seyhmus-gungoren x * sin(c) ?

Comment: Thanks @joriki I first intended to use two dollars then indented then changed to 4 dollars then dollars appeared! )) then finally changed again.

Comment: @Synxmax yes you re right.

Comment: Strings like "sin" are interpreted as concatenations of variable names and are therefore italicized. To get the right font and spacing for function names like $\sin$, you can use the predefined commands like `\sin`, or if you need a function name like $\operatorname{erf}$ for which there's no predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{erf}`.

Comment: Wikipedia page is so complex at least to me so much formula , Thank u sir

Comment: @Synxmax believe me it is not complex. You also need to learn some basic stuff by your own. You can not ask always to others right? For example if you use "ctrl+f" and type "Trigonometric ratios in right triangles" on the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle  then you will get exactly what you wanna and even more..